# Find Matches Between UnSorted Arrays AND Retrieve Corresponding Values for Matches Found

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

I have two pivot tables (call them 1 and 2) that contain current and prior day options data, respectively. I run several calculations using data combined from these tables, and in all cases the match key is the option contract (strike) price.

The issue I seek to resolve occurs when options strike contracts aren't identical day-over-day. For example, a contract can be introduced at a new price that did not exist previously (or the opposite -- when a contract no longer offered to the market is removed day-over day). Both scenarios result in an offset between table row data.

The use of INDEX and MATCH seemed to be a viable solution, whereby current day strike prices are the match key. If that key exists in both tables, print corresponding current and prior day values and use this output for the comparison formulas.

I've created a file with simplified test data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zSMNM46UROXD9JYzgcM1k9ztHBLjUBKKhK6XtIdyMDE/edit#gid=0). Columns G-I contain INDEX MATCH statements that should illustrate what I need to accomplish in terms of output, and I've highlighted rows affected by the row offset created with contracts are not identical, day over day.

I've attempted several solutions; this just isn't my wheelhouse and could use some help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required solution needed to print values based on key matches between two tables.

Based on the data I work with, uncontrollable offsets between table rows are frequent occurrences. For this reason (and as mentioned in the original post), use of INDEX MATCH, VLOOKUP, etc., did not work in this scenario because they seek matches in corresponding cells.

The solution I discovered involves the use of SUPERSQL, a pair of app scripts that enable use of SQL (i.e. SELECT and JOIN statements).

I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93JfUPdnLhE) video to understand SUPERSQL usage; its description includes a link to an installation video, if anyone runs across a need similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

## Logically it makes sense to use the most current data.

### If your formulas must depend on a single value for some kind of comparison.

The formula you used in column V is

```
=IF(OLD_STRIKE=NEW_STRIKE,OLD_STRIKE,FALSE)
```

I recommend that if you need to make a comparison, the most recent input is most likely the most correct. So you could use

```
=IF(OLD_STRIKE=NEW_STRIKE,OLD_STRIKE,NEW_STRIKE)
```

Another option is to average the two, I don't recommend this because if something drastic changed overnight or if there was some kind of an outlier in the data (like a stray 0) it could throw off your data. But either way here is that option.

```
=IF(OLD_STRIKE = NEW_STRIKE, OLD_STRIKE, AVERAGE(OLD_STRIKE, NEW_STRIKE))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. A strike price is an absolute - it cannot be averaged. It is the set price at which a derivative (i.e. stock option) contract can be bought or sold when exercised, and by a specified expiration date.

Options dealers introduce contracts at strike prices based on what they perceive as demand, and this can occur day-over-day.

Hence the need I described to manage the instance when a contract that did not previously exist is provided to the market, or the reverse - a contract that previously existed no longer is offered.

Comment: Based on your response, I realized that I provided an inadequate amount of info to describe the need and its conditions. 

I think this could be better described as a lookup function between unsorted arrays. I'll see what that leads to.

Comment: I've updated the original post according to a better understanding of the issue I seek to solve, and further simplified the test data to illustrate the issue and needed resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the puts as your primary key,

Your problem is that you are using your strike values to decern a purchase, but, the purchase is defined by the put value. Here is a sample of the data I observed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Lkib1tCFEw9upEIUmpubhWUVGbQ4RDXboGe9nR4Qdg/edit?usp=sharing

There is a 100% match between strike values and put values. So if you are trying to compare a certain purchase maybe look towards the put value instead.

Comment: As mentioned, this is sample data. I can add the full set, if needed.

Your initial comment regarding logic was spot on in that prior day data used for comparison purposes must key off current day data.

However, the strike must be that key, as both put and call contracts can exist at a strike price.

For example, a dependent calculation shows change to open interest in either put or call contracts if a strike shows a change.

Ideal solution: if a strike present in current day data is present in prior day data, then required values are retrieved from both sets. If not, nothing prints.